# Google OAuth Session not being saved on Chrome

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm testing a Google OAuth login with Laravel and I'm facing a problem with the sessions not being saved on Google Chrome (if you open a new tab you need to log in again), it works just fine with other browsers (Firefox, Edge Opera). I checked if the problem was local by clearing cache/cookis/extensions.

I noticed on the Network tab a CORS error / 405 / Preflight request on Chrome while on other browsers this doesn't appear.